# c# TCP socket not receiving messages

Tags: c#, sockets, tcpclient

I am new to sockets in c# and cannot see the problem in my code.
I have a C++ app that sends a series of 8 messages when my C# application connects to its socket.
I know that the c++ application works because it has been tested elsewhere.

This is my c# socket creation code

```
m_tcpESSClient = new TcpClient(AddressFamily.InterNetwork);
m_tcpESSClient.ReceiveBufferSize = 4096;
m_tcpESSClient.BeginConnect(
IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.01"),
8082,
new AsyncCallback(ConnectCallback2),
m_tcpESSClient);
```

This is the connect callback

```
private void ConnectCallback2(IAsyncResult result)
{
    m_tcpESSClient.EndConnect(result);
    State state = new State();
    state.buffer = new byte[m_tcpESSClient.ReceiveBufferSize];
    state.offset = 0;

    NetworkStream networkStream = m_tcpESSClient.GetStream();
            networkStream.BeginRead(
              state.buffer,
              state.offset,
              state.buffer.Length,
              ReadCallback2,
              state
              );
}
```

and this is the read callback

```
private void ReadCallback2(IAsyncResult result)
{            
NetworkStream networkStream = m_tcpESSClient.GetStream();
int byteCount = networkStream.EndRead(result);

State state = result.AsyncState as State;
state.offset += byteCount;

// Show message received on UI
Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
{                
    ListBox.Items.Add("Received ");
});

state.offset = 0;
networkStream.BeginRead(
state.buffer,
state.offset,
state.buffer.Length,
ReadCallback2,
state);
```

The problem is that all messages sent by the c++ application are not received.
Please can anyone see what is wrong with my socket code.

Comment: Have you tried to set some breakpoints in callbacks and debug what happens? Also, why do you use APM and not tasks with async/await?

Comment: `m_tcpESSClient` pff https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/general-naming-conventions

Comment: @PabloRecalde that's the c++ convention that he is using. As he said, he's new to C# Sockets and C# in general, I guess.

Comment: So, your C++ app is listening on 127.0.0.1 port 8082, right? Then, two questions: 1) Do you see C# connection attempts inside C++ code? 2) Do you see your C++ app is actually listening via running the `netstat /a /b` command in the command prompt?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TCP doesn't have  a concept of messages. TCP operates on streams.

This means that even though the C++ application might be issuing eight separate `Write` calls, you might receive all of that data with a single `Read` (or require multiple `Read`s to read data written by a single `Write`). The items you add to the list box have no relation to the amount of "messages" the C++ application has sent you.

To actually identify individual messages, you need to have a message-based protocol on top of TCP streams. You can't just rely on individual `Read`s. In any case, you need to parse the data you receive over the socket.

Comment: This is the single biggest concept overlooked or just generally not understood by programmers new to network programming. I wish it could just be plastered all over the place.

Comment: Thanks for the simple explanation. I obviously misunderstood the concepts involved. I will implement parsing the data received.